# How do these for statements work in this directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to figure out how to convert a phone number from alphabetized to numeric form. I found this code that works fine but I am having trouble understanding why it does what it does. I understand the .get method, but I don't understand why when called the code inside char_num_map gets the corresponding number from the list. Could someone explain why?

```
char_numbers = [('abc',2), ('def',3), ('ghi',4), ('jkl',5), 
('mno',6), ('pqrs',7), ('tuv',8), ('wxyz',9)]
char_num_map = {c:i for k,i in char_numbers for c in k}
phone = '800-FUN-KIDS'
result = "".join(str(char_num_map.get(i,i)) for i in 
phone.lower())
result
```

Thanks in advance, any help would be really appriciated.

Comment: what is the problem exactly?

Comment: See this tutorial on [dictionary comprehension](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-dictionary-comprehension)

Comment: it first builds a letter => number lookup dict, then applies it in a generator comprehension passed to `str.join` to convert letter phone number to digit phone number

Comment: @R. Vice see my answer. I provided an example step by step

Comment: @seralouk yes I understand why it works now your answer laid it out perfect, thank you

Comment: @Barmar dude that is exactly what I was looking for thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `char_num_map` is a dictionary containing the mapping from letters to numbers. The letters are the `keys` and the mapped numbers the `values`.

Next, the `for i in phone.lower()` iterates over the `phone` variable and returns one by one the contains of the variable.

For the `dict.get` method the full function is like this: `dict.get(key, default = None)`

> Parameters key − This is the Key to be searched in the dictionary.
>
> default − This is the Value to be returned in case key does not exist

So, you pass the `i` in the `char_num_map.get(i,i)`.

---

**Example step by step:**

First, run this:

```
for i in phone.lower():
    pass

print(i)
#s
```

This returns `i = 's'`.

Next, type:

```
char_num_map.get(i,i)
```

This returns:

```
7
```

**The reason is that `get` tries to find a `key` named `s` and it returns its `value`** otherwise, it would return 's'.

Comment: thank you, this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: I am glab that i could help. Please consider accepting and upvoting my answer